# Flash system.img file without fastboot over USB

Tags: rom-flashing, fastboot, aosp

I want to flash a different version of a `system.img` and normally this would be done with fastboot via USB but the device I am trying to do this to I cant use adb/fastboot over USB and I have to use adb over Ethernet instead. Once I reboot into the bootloader to try to use fastboot it obviously wont see the device since I use Ethernet so is there a way to just flash the new system.img file without fastboot?

Device has an sdcard slot, is there a way to use that?

Also note I dont have any of the other image files (boot,recovery,etc...) so I wont be able to create a zip file

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118246/discussion-on-question-by-tyczj-flash-system-img-file-without-fastboot-over-usb).